# Groovy adding primes taking forever

Tags: performance, groovy

This is Project Euler number 10. It should add all primes below two million. Anything above something like 200000 takes forever, and 200000 takes a very long time. I think the final answer is above MAXINT, but I'm dealing with that later.

Why is it so slow?

```
def isPrime(num, primes)
{
    primes.find { it <= Math.sqrt(num) && it != 1 && it != num && num % it == 0 } == null
}

def primes = [] 
def min = 2
def max = 10 - 1

(min..max).findAll { it % 2 == 1 || it == 2 }.each { i ->
    if (isPrime(i, primes))
    {
        primes.add(i);
    }
}

def sum = primes.inject { sum, item -> sum + item }

print sum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... it probably has a lot to do with iterating over the list of primes and not short circuiting it when past the square root...

With the following C# IsPrime code, the code runs in a half a second:

**FAST: 0.525 seconds**

```
static bool IsPrime(int number, List<int> primes)
{
    bool prime = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < primes.Count; i++ )
    {
        int theprime = primes[i];
        if (theprime > Math.Sqrt(number))
        {
            break;
        }

        if (number % theprime == 0)
        {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}
```

However, with this C# IsPrime code (essentially the same as the Groovy code in the original post), the same performance issues remain:

**SLOW**

```
static bool IsPrime(int number, List<int> primes)
{
    return primes.FirstOrDefault(o => o <= Math.Sqrt(number) && o != 1 && o != number && number % o == 0) == default(int);
}
```

**After a little more testing**, the problem is related to not short circuiting at the square root. Using takeWhile in groovy also runs slowly (it is probably creating a new list).

This code does not short circuit at the square root, and runs slower than a minute (I stopped it.):

**SLOW (more than a minute)**

```
def isPrime(num, primes)
{
    def root = Math.sqrt(num)
    def prime = true
    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
    {
        def aprime = primes[i];
        if (aprime <= root && aprime != 1 && aprime != num && num % aprime == 0)
        {
            prime = false
            break
        }
    }
    prime
}
```

This also runs slower than a minute:

**SLOW (more than a minute)**

```
def isPrime(num, primes)
{
    def root = Math.sqrt(num)
    primes.takeWhile { it <= root }?.find { it != 1 && it != num && num % it == 0 } == null
}
```

Even though the equivalent C# code runs in 0.559 seconds (takeWhile must be implemented a lot better in C#):

**FAST: 0.559 seconds**

```
static bool IsPrime(int number, List<int> primes)
{
    int root = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number));
    return primes.TakeWhile(o => o <= root).FirstOrDefault(o => o != 1 && o != number && number % o == 0) == default(int);
}
```

I **finally** got half decent performance in Groovy by both short circuiting and not using takeWhile:

**MEDIUM: 51 seconds**

```
def isPrime(num, primes)
{
    def root = Math.sqrt(num)
    def prime = true
    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
    {
        def aprime = primes[i];
        if (aprime > root)
        {
            break
        }
        if (aprime != 1 && aprime != num && num % aprime == 0)
        {
            prime = false
            break
        }
    }
    prime
}
```

Comment: This approach works great when dealing with a small number of primes, but the OP is trying to find the sum of all primes less than 2 million. That's a staggering number of iterations. I did a LOT of optimization writing Python code for this problem, and couldn't come within orders of magnitude of marginally quick results with this implementation.

Comment: @adsmith OP and this answerer are the same person. This runs in a couple of seconds.

Comment: @adsmith 0.525 seconds. Just measured it.

Comment: Try with `@CompileStatic` and make sure to use the very latest Groovy version. Avoiding `findAll` (creates a new collection) and `inject` may help as well.

Comment: @adsmith My friend just implemented this in 0.156 seconds in Delphi (not the Sieve of Eratosthenes).

Comment: I'll let the results do the talking. I don't need to use a different algorithm when this one is not close to inefficient for the input.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser gave you a good place to start.  Be sure to know what methods like `findall` are actually doing before using them.  A plain for loop will help here by not creating a collection of every possible number and then iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorWGarvey and PeterNiderwieser. I will try y'alls suggestions when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

When I solved this problem, I did so by implementing a Sieve of Eratosthenes. I won't tell you how to implement it (that's your job), but [here's some background reading.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) I did a good amount of tweaking to try and get the brute-force method to work, and never came up with a result in less than a few minutes. My final answer ran in less than a second.

If you DO have any problems with implementation, change the question and we can hopefully give you a hand!

Comment: Thanks, that would be definitely be faster. Though I'm curious why the above code is slow. I wrote almost the same thing in C# and it runs in a couple seconds. And as I'm moving my changes over to groovy, it's still slow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a time complexity of order `n^(3/2)`, which is over `10^9` if `n := 2000000`. A rule of thumb in programming competitions is that when your code does more than `~10^8 operations`, you should consider a different approach. In your case, the famous [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) will work fine.